# Query for user roles

Tags: php, functions, user-roles

How do I query for a specific user role?

```
if (is_user_logged_in() && user_role == "user") {}
```

The part I'm unsure about is user_role.

**Is there a way I can ask WordPress to check for a specific user role by name/string**?

Comment: Use [`get_user_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) with `slug` or `user_login`. It returns [an object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by#Default_usage), so go through it accordingly.

Comment: so `get_user_by('roles','13')` ? 13 equals admin for example?
Or can I just combine these? Because I need a role, not a specific user.
So... ID -> caps?

Comment: Then if I get you correctly, you need this: `if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can("role_name") ) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for specific user role using following code -

```
if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('administrator')) {}
```

The function current_user_can() takes role name as parameter. 
For more info - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can/

Answer (score 0):

You can make WordPress query for a certain user role by using `current_user_can("role_name")`.

Thanks to [Mayeenul Islam](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/22728/mayeenul-islam) for providing the solution!